# How to Define Dynamic Model in Spring Framework

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data

I am using **Spring Framework** as my back end

I have define know as Entity class The Entity class know contain 5 Fields

Below is the class , The code below dose not have setter getter part to make shorter and cleaner

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TblKnow")
public class Know {

    @Id 
    private Double idKnow;
    private String SubjectKnow;
    private String BodyKnow;
    private String ImgKnow;
    private double CountView;
```

In **JpaRepository interface** i want to only query two column not all of columns.

```
public interface KnowRepository extends JpaRepository<Know,Double> {



     @Query("SELECT idKnow,SubjectKnow FROM Know")
     public Page<Know> findCByOrderByIdKnowDesc(Pageable pageable);
```

**Problem:**  i try to run but  i get below exception

**java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot create TypedQuery for query with more than one return using requested result type [java.lang.Long]**

But if i use without below query it is fine

```
 public Page<Know> findAllByOrderByIdKnowDesc(Pageable pageable);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom constructor and use that to select only some fields in JPA query.

```
public Know(Double idKnow, String SubjectKnow) {
    this.idKnow = idKnow;
    this.SubjectKnow = SubjectKnow;
}
```

And the use this constructor in JPA query. Make sure you use complete path of class with package.

```
@Query("SELECT NEW packagePath.Know(idKnow,SubjectKnow) FROM Know")
```

Answer (score 1):

query :

```
public Page<Know> findAllByOrderByIdKnowDesc(Pageable pageable);
```

works dut to you select Know objects with fields that are mapped correct into Know class (and after wrapped into Page).

with query :

```
 @Query("SELECT idKnow,SubjectKnow FROM Know")
 public Page<Know> findCByOrderByIdKnowDesc(Pageable pageable);
```

returns some custome bean/object that spring data can't map in correct way into Know class (as you declared it as expected return class wrapped into Page). add counstructor into Know with idKnow,SubjectKnow fields , or you can wrap it into some DTO with idKnow,SubjectKnow fields.